# how to use onClickListener method of Button on a ListView

Tags: android, button, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a custom `ListView` which contains a `Button`. The function of this button is Delete button. Whenever user click to this button, the current Row will be deleted.

- How can I do it?
- How can I set `onClickListener` for this button?
- How can I catch the row Id which this button is on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `setOnItemClickListener()` on listview if u need only row id

Comment: [See this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Answer (score 7):

In your **Custom Adapater** class's `getView()`

```
buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
   {
     //  Use position parameter of your getView() in this method it will current position of Clicked row button
    // code for current Row deleted...              
   }
});
```

Comment: Which I earlier need to findById  ?

Answer (score 4):

First, that will be very easy for you to handle the click on this item.
You just have to add a listener with: `myButton.setOnClickListener(mBuyButtonClickListener)`. This action is usually done on the `getView(...)` implementation of your `ListView`.

Your listener can know what is the item position of the button by using `myListView.getPositionForView(myButton)`. 
Look at this sample of the listener :

```
private OnClickListener mBuyButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = getListView().getPositionForView(v);
        if (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            //DO THE STUFF YOU WANT TO DO WITH THE position
        }
    }
};
```

When this is done, you should have problems to handle the click on the item itself and some other touch event propagation.

So, you should read [this article](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525) that fully describes the use of multiple touchable areas inside a `ListView`. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use this inside the getView method of your adapter class.

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
   {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked everywhere and non of the answers helped me until one did.

What i did was create a HolderView and wrapped up all my textviews and other widgets in the getView mathod of the adpater:

put this class in:

```
    static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
}
```

and i also decalared the same ones normally as they are seperate now:

```
TextView text1;
TextView text2;
TextView text3;
```

then declare all the views and widgets after inflating the layout in getView:

```
holder = new ViewHolder(); 
holder.text1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2single);
holder.text2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3single);
holder.text3 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView4single);
```

inside the onClick method, i used:

```
View parentView = (View) v.getParent();
```

and then declared all my widgets again using this parentview:

```
text1 = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.textView2single);
text2 = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.textView3single);
text3 = (TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.textView4single);
```

In doing this im forcing my onClick to get the parent position of the list view item, therefore all widgets inside that parent can be called easily, then you can do what you like with it. This is the only way i have found that works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom list view adapter, extend BaseAdapter and implement OnClickListener

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {}
```

override the getView method

```
@Override
public View getView(int
        position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.b1= (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

    }
}
```

now override the onclick method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
            //button b1 click event 
            break;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {
    Button b1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new View type variable and assign it with currenView(Check if iit is null).Define variables(ImageButton taken here) and set viewId in the below mentioned way.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemview=convertView;
        if (itemview==null)
        {
            itemview=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.group_list,parent,false);

        }
        final group_contacts currentcontact=g_contact.get(position);
        ImageButton delete=(ImageButton) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_delete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Add your code here to run on tapping button
            }
        });
        return itemview;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `onClickListener()` method on a `Button` of a `ListView`, you Must Apply `onClickListener()` on the Button in `Adapter`'s `getView` Methode.

But the problem is, you will not be able to get the Value from the `position`parameter of `getView`.

To get the `position`of the Button you have Touched, you must Call `getPositionForView()`method on your `ListView`.

Lets discus with an Example For Better Understanding,

- Consider you have a `ListView`named `ExampleListview`
- A `Button` on it named `ExampleButton`and u want to use `onClickListener()` on it.

  ```
  Examplebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
          final int position= ExampleListview..getPositionForView(v);
     /*Where 'v' is actually the 'View' object Which you are clicking.*/ 

  /*you can now right your code her & determine the your desired button by
    using the position parameter */
  }
  ```